# Making Classes Variable

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Can any one tell me if there is a way, and if so how to, make an activity implement an entire class based on an `if then` or `switch` statement, essentially making the class itself a variable? [I want to display a particular list class (activity) in a tab depending on a value received from an OnItemClicked event in another tab].

To give you an idea of what I think I might be looking for:

```
if(position == 1){//run class 1}

if(position == 2){//run class 2}
```

THANKS.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming#Java)?

```
interface MyService {
   void doWork();
}

class CoolMyService {
   void doWork() { /* do something */ }
}

class AnotherMyService {
   void doWork() { /* do something else */ }
}

MyService service;
if(position == 1){ service = new CoolMyService(); }

if(position == 2){ service = new AnotherMyService() } 

service.doWork();
```

I don't know how many items there are in your list, but you can adapt the example above to load objects dynamically as appropriate. Just remember that you can use polymorphism and a defined [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) to ensure integrity. Then put the real work in concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You might want a (n abstract) factory pattern.

Take a look at [it inside the Java Design Patterns](http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/abstract_factory_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receiver

```
if (position == 1){
    sent broadcast event to one class 
}if(position === 2){
    sent broadcast event to another class
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into using Class.forName()

```
Class oClass = Class.forName(strClassName);
Tab myTab = (Tab) oClass.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem.

My first solution would be implementing the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Pattern) with [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), passing the class as an argument to the factory method:

code:

```
Class impClass;
if (position == 1) {
  impClass = First.class;
} else if (position == 1) {
  impClass = Second.class;
}
Object myObject = ObjectFactory.createObject(impClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract factory or prototype patterns fit your needs http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern